# Make SVN tag immutable right after creation

Tags: svn

Is there a way to make a SVN tag immutable right after it is created? I know there are pre-commit hooks what would prevent commits, but new files can still be added to the tag folder. We are looking for a way for developers to add a folder to the tag directory, and have that folder become immutable right after creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion tags are mutable. They're basically the same as branches or other copied folders. You're depending upon the good faith of people not to change them. The good thing is that Subversion tracks everything. You can easily check the history of a tag to see if it was changed, and find out who changed it and why.

However, I like to prevent people from accidentally checking out a tag, then later making modifications and committing the changes because they thought they were on a branch.

When I first used Subversion way back in version 1.2, I was very concerned that the available pre-commit hooks only had two permissions: `read-only` and `read-write`. You could allow users to create tags and modify them, or not allow users to create tags. I wrote [my own](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that added `add-only` which does exactly what you want: Create immutable tags. You can *create a tag* via `svn cp`, but once created, you can't modify it. You're free to give it a try. The hook is called `new-pre-commit-hook.pl`.